# Pattern recognition teachniques that allow input as sequence of different length

Tags: matlab, time, series

I am trying to classify water end-use events expressed as a time-series sequences into appropriate categories (e.g. toilet, tap, shower, etc). My first attempt using HMM shows a quite promising result with an average accuracy of 80%. I just wonder if there is any other techniques that allow the training input as time-series sequences of different length like HMM does rather than the extracted feature vector of each sequence. I have tried Conditional Random Field (CRF) and SVM ;however, as far as I know, these two techniques require input as a pre-computed feature vector and the length of all input vectors must be the same for training purpose. I am not sure if I am right or wrong at this point. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks, Will

Comment: Did you find an answer to that yourself and would like to share it?